# Use xtics in 3D gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

In my data file, I have three columns: one string and two numeric values. Now I want to create a 3D plot using `gnuplot`. Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
Need 1 or 3 columns for cartesian data
```

This is my data file:

```
"Str1" 0 0
"Str1" 1 0
"Str1" 2 0

"Str2" 0 10
"Str2" 1 10
"Str2" 2 10

"Str3" 0 10
"Str3" 1 10
"Str3" 2 10
```

This is my gnuplot script:

```
set surface 
set contour surface

set view 60, 30, 1, 1
set clabel '%8.2f'
set key right
set title "Graph Title"
set xlabel "X Axis Label"
set ylabel "Y Axis Label"
set zlabel "Z Axis Label"

set term pdfcairo color dashed font 'FreeSans,9'
set output "output.pdf"
splot "data2.txt" using xtic(1):2:3 notitle

set output
```

I do not understand what the problem is. I used xtic in a 2D figure already. Additionally, there are three "coordinates". Do I have to define something special for the x axis?

Thank you!

UPDATE:

The following figure is generated using this script:

```
set grid
set view 60, 30, 1, 1
set clabel '%8.2f'
set key right
set title "Graph Title"
set xlabel "X label (String)"
set ylabel "number 1"
set zlabel "number 2"

set xtics ("Str1" 0, "Str2" 1, "Str3" 2)

set term pdfcairo color dashed font 'FreeSans,9'
set output "rpiCluster2.pdf"
splot "data2.txt" using (int($0)/3):2:3 with linespoints

set output
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xtic` is not a coordinate, but a string. You still need an x-coordinate:

```
splot "data2.txt" using (int($0)/3):2:3:xtic(1) notitle
```

Note, that the labels aren't written several times over each other, but only once.

In order to have an automatic solution you can use the `stats` command. That doesn't directly count the blocks, but the blank lines. For your test data the following works fine:

```
stats "data2.txt" using 2 nooutput
n = int(STATS_records/(STATS_blank + 1))

splot "data2.txt" using (int($0)/n):2:3:xtic(1) notitle
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without knowing the `3`?

Comment: I would also be interested in a dynamic solution

Comment: Additionally, the x axis is not completely filled... which means that on the "right" site of the x axis there is empty room. I tried to fix this using xrange[0:4], but didn't work...

Comment: @TomFenech See my edit. Also, my assumption about the multiple tics being written was wrong. The current solution should be fine.

Comment: @strauberry I don't understand which white space you mean. For me the xaxis looks fine. Does it happen with the script and the data you showed?

Comment: Updated my question. How can I use different colors for each string line :-)? Thank you!

Comment: Please ask a new question, as the second part is a rather different thing. Maybe it could be done with `linecolor palette`, `linecolor variable` or `linecolor rgb variable`. But that depends on the details. Please include enough information.